# Give an example, if any, of a non-constant periodic function, discontinuous, but which has a fundamental period .

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, periodic-functions

**Question**

> Give an example, if any, of a non-constant periodic function, discontinuous in a subset of $\mathbb R$, but which has a period that is smaller than all the others.

**My example**

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sin x&\text { if } x\in]0,\pi[,]2\pi,3\pi[,... \newline -\sin x&\text { if } x\in]\pi,2\pi[,]3\pi,4\pi[,...\end{cases}$$

It works? Can you suggest me some more? Thanks in advance

Comment: Let $f$ be any strictly monotonic  discontinuous function on $[0,1)$ and $f(x)=f(x-n)$ for $n \leq x <n+1, n \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Let $f(x)=1$ for $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\notin \mathbb{Q}.$ Then every rational number is a period. Hence the  period is "smaller than all the others".

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc But in your example, $f$ doesn't have a smallest period.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "period that is smaller than all the others" ?

Comment: For example, $f\equiv 1$ is periodic, all positive numbers are periods but there is no inf$\{periods\}$. Must have a minimum positive period

Comment: In my opinion the title of the question is misleading.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes, the wording is bad, but it is easy to guess what OP wants. The function should have a smallest positive period.

Comment: @geetha290krm So the question should be: are there discontinuous periodic functions with a smallest positive period ? Clearly one can take any nonconstant periodic function with period $a>0$ and redefine it at the points $na$ by adding $1.$

Comment: That is the basic idea in my comment. To make sure that it doesn't have periods less than $1$ I took $f$ to be strictly montonic in $[0,1]$. @RyszardSzwarc

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good at English. My example works?

Comment: $]2(k-1)\pi,2k\pi[$ and $](k-1)\pi,k\pi[$ have points in common, so your definition of $f(x)$does not make sense.

Comment: @geetha290krm   You're right, I'll edit